# Draw circles inside pie - d3 chart

Tags: d3.js

Hi i have created a pie chart using https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235
How to add a circle inside each arcs - Example. Need to draw two circle inside 25-44 pie, two circle inside 18-24 pie, two circle inside <5 so on...

How to make sure the circle drawn lies inside those arc. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it just as how you making label on the pie chart.

```
//arc for 1st circle
var circleArc1 = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 70)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

//arc for 2nd circle
var circleArc2 = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 100)
    .innerRadius(radius - 100);
```

Then use the the arc function to calculate the translate

```
      g.append("circle")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + circleArc1.centroid(d) + ")"; }) //use arc 1
          .style("fill", "purple")
          .attr("r", "10");

  g.append("circle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + circleArc2.centroid(d) + ")"; }) //use arc2
      .style("fill", "violet")
      .attr("r", "10")
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/i0Q3Tj15O2rI3jURocYZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you.. but i have n number of circles which i want to place inside each of the arc. in your solution you have found the circleArc1 using the hard  coded value of radius -70 and for circleArc2 = radius-100,...

Comment: Please help.. Need to add those circles inside arc without passing 70, 100 for each circle

Comment: Please write the full correct question its not good a practice to change the requirement, as solution is provided.

Comment: Sure.I have created a circle packing using http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530 . i want to represent the packing inside pie.

Comment: I want to represent the packing inside pie(those circles inside pie). Please help

Comment: I think its best to delete this question and ask a fresh question with all your requirements so that other people can help you.